# Simple fadein and fadeout effect onclick without frameworks

Tags: javascript, html, css, fadein, fadeout

I'm looking for the simplest way to fade a div onclick of another div and then hide it or fade in a div. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `setInterval()` and CSS **opacity**

Comment: Do you have any specific code to accomplish this? @A.O.

Comment: @A.O. http://jsfiddle.net/g7QNH/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a great javascript fadeout effect:

```
function fadeout(element) {
    var i = 1;
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (i <= 0.1){
            clearInterval(timer);
            element.style.display = 'none';
        }
        element.style.opacity = i;
        element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + i * 100 + ")";
        i -= i * 0.1;
    }, 50);
}
```

Here is a working example with fade in and fade out for a div that says "Hello World!":

```
<html>
<script>
function animator(element) {
    this.el = element;
    this.state = 0;
    this.fadeout = function() {
        var element = this.el;
        var op = 1;
        var timer = setInterval(function () {
            if (op <= 0.0) {
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
            element.style.opacity = op;
            element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
            op -= 0.1;
        }, 50);
    };
    this.fadein = function() {
        var element = this.el;
        var op = 0.0;
        var timer = setInterval(function () {
            if (op >= 1.0) {
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
            element.style.opacity = op;
            element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
            op += 0.1;
        }, 50);
    };
}
function initfader() {
    show = new animator(document.getElementById("div1"));
}
</script>
<body onload="initfader();">
    <div id="div1">
        <h2>Hello World!</h2>
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="show.fadein();" value="in" />
    <input type="button" onclick="show.fadeout();" value="out" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @elleiospizzaman Can you get this to work with your fade effect? http://jsfiddle.net/g7QNH/

Comment: I just added a working example that will fade the div in and out.

Answer (score 0):

there is a CSS property called **"transition"**:
it works without javascript!
if you don't mind having :hover instead of click.
here is an example with a :hover effect and images inside another element.

DON'T forget the vendor prefixes as well! so you make sure that this works in many older browsers as well!

```
/* Normal */
a img {
opacity: .6;
-webkit-transition:opacity 500ms ease-out;
-moz-transition:opacity 500ms ease-out;
-o-transition:opacity 500ms ease-out;
transition:opacity 500ms ease-out;
}

/* ":hover" */
a:hover img {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition:opacity 500ms ease-out;
-moz-transition:opacity 500ms ease-out;
-o-transition:opacity 500ms ease-out;
transition:opacity 500ms ease-out;
}
```

Comment: This isn't exactly an answer considering the need of the onclick event was specified.

Comment: that's why I said "if you don't mind having :hover instead of click". :-)  - the JS solution only works with browsers which support "opacity".